# Set default Ruby version in rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm attempting to setup **rbenv** to use Ruby 3.0.0 for Jekyll (according to [this tutorial](https://www.shouvikbasak.net/website/jekyll-on-macos-apple-m1-solved/) 3.0.0 is necessary on macos w/ M1)

I installed rbenv with homebrew and ruby 3.0.0 with `rbenv install 3.0.0` and set to global with `rbenv global 3.0.0`

I attempted to add ruby 3.0.0 to my path with:
`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`. When I restart my terminal, it seems like it's not pointing to the correct ruby version:

```
$ gem env home
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0
```

[EDIT]
Removing a previous point, as it's not relevant to the question regarding default Ruby version.

Comment: You are free to choose whatever shell you want. Didn't you install on purpose?

Comment: if you don't use zsh you don't need to append to ~/.zshrc, as you mentioned. BTW did you checked if rbenv is running with (type rbenv)? It must return something like "rbenv is a function ..."

Comment: @AndreDurao I haven't previously used zsh to my knowledge, though it seems like I'm using it based on the first message when iTerm opens. also, when I type zsh, my terminal updates from `[mac-name]:~ username$` to `username@[mac-name] ~ %`


rbenv appears to be running. `type rbenv` returns `rbenv is hashed (/opt/homebrew/bin/rbenv)`.


I'm still uncertain why Ruby 3.0.0 version isn't being used.

Comment: There are two unrelated problems here (one about rbenv, and one about the error in your bash configuration files). Ask therefore **two** questions on Stackoverflow. As for the discussion on bash vs. zsh on the Mac, see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250722978).

Comment: BTW: Fiddling with .zshrc is pointless if you are using bash. Also, shell configuration files are usually manipulated by a tool called a _text editor_ and not by hacking `echo` commands on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that this brings up a second question about zsh vs bash, but the main question still remains about setting the default Ruby version. @user1934428 was there a point to the text editor comment? it still seems like my original question is unanswered as to why Ruby 3.0.0 is not being set as default.

Comment: The point refered to your remark _I attempted to add ruby  ...._, and I tried to explain why this was not a very sensible idea to do. As for what you call "original question", thank you for editing your post - now it focus at least on one problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rbenv documentation, you have to put into your .bashrc the command

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Try this, start up a new terminal, and then do the `rbenv global` stuff.